# How to change only ag-heder-column header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ag-grid

I have an `ag-grid` like below which has two headers. And I wanna change the height of header which is in that red rectangle as u can see.

[image]

Im able to change all headers height with this one

```
gridOptions.api.setHeaderHeight(100);
```

but this one changes both of them, I only want to change that red one how can I do that?I also tried other methods from `ag-grid api` like below but none of them worked.

```
setGroupHeaderHeight(heightInPx)
setFloatingFiltersHeight(heightInPx)
setPivotHeaderHeight(heightInPx)    
setPivotGroupHeaderHeight(heightInPx)
```

I also tried to change height of that div with `jQuery` but didnt work seems like ag-grid has different algorithm to set header height.

[image]

[Here is a working plunker example.](https://plnkr.co/edit/WGBE07F3vR2TpG5Z)

Comment: Are you open to CSS solution?

Comment: yes of course @m4n0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do. Get the default header height the top header row should be set to. Then set the header height to whatever you want, then set the grouping header height to the default header height, which will override what you set the header height to.

```
const defaultHeaderHeight = gridOptions.api.getSizesForCurrentTheme().headerHeight;
gridOptions.api.setHeaderHeight(100);
gridOptions.api.setGroupHeaderHeight(defaultHeaderHeight);
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9hHKRnNbY9T3Hu4C).